# Replace html button value with php and store it in database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

> //Following code to generate 25
>   Button with unique name for each
>   button
>   // 25 buttons contains value
>   from 1 to 25
>   // like
>   btn1='1',btn2='2' ... btn25='25'

```
 <?php 
                  $j=0;
                        for($i=1;$i<=25;$i++)
                        {
                                $j++;
                                    ?> 
                                    <td><input type='button' id='btn' name="btn<?php echo $i;?>" value='<?php echo $i;?>' onclick="cnt(btn<?php echo $i;?>);" ></td>
                                    <?php                               
                                    if($j==5)
                                    {
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                        echo "<tr>";
                                        $j=0;
                                    }           
                        }
                 ?>
```

// and using concantation i'm inserting button values seqhence into database
// like user will click on first 5 button i will insert seq=1-2-3-4-5 which are html button values

// and then using php insert query i'm inserting the sequene in db
// concantation code i'm not given here

```
$con="INSERT INTO `vector`.`signup` (`userid` ,`seq`)VALUES ('".$usr."', '".$seq."')";

     mysql_query($con) or die  ('Bad Input');
?>
```

see this databse picture

http://i53.tinypic.com/1zudjo.jpg

Now my prb is i want to store different values in database .. for each buton
like btn1='1' has value 1 when user will click i want to store diffvalue like 'a1' . which should not
available to user on client side .. i want to do with php ..

how can i change html button value with php code to store in databse...

i want btn1='1' to be btn1='a1' in database..

Comment: So you mean to store something that is not in the button itself? If yes, is 'a' in a1 always the same.. or will it change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$databasevalue = 'a' . $_POST['btn1'];
```

Seems rather obvious... just prepend whatever you want to the value coming out of the form.

Comment: bt this value will echo in HTML source ??

Comment: Then remove the value before building the form next time around? Or store the special value seperately from the form value. Sounds like you're making a mountain out of a mole hill. If this special value can't ever be seen by a user, then you should never mix it in with data that will be seen.